# Build a Docker Image with a Maven settings.xml in it - Is it a Bad Practice?

Tags: docker, maven

We have this use case where we want to run acceptance tests on our application with maven. For this we are looking into building our docker image with maven settings.xml copied into it. Obviously, the settings xml contains sensitive data about connection to remote artefact repos etc.
I am in a dilemma, whether we should copy it in the docker image, or is it a bad practice and we should be looking into other ways to achieve this.

Edit - Another point, our docker images are pushed to private registries which are accessible only to authorised users

Comment: The question is why you need a `settings.xml` inside a docker image? Usually you package your application into the docker image but not the build part... And all the arguments given by the answer of David Maze...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's absolutely no security around the contents of a Docker image.  Anyone who gets the image can trivially read its `docker history` and read or copy arbitrary files out of the image.

As such I'd try very hard to keep credentials out of my Docker image build process entirely.  If the `settings.xml` file has usernames and passwords in it, it's much better to find a different way to do the setup required.  Similarly, adding an ssh private key, AWS credentials, or a GitHub access token to an image will compromise those credentials.

If the `settings.xml` file only contains internal hostnames (but not credentials), or if the password is intentionally bad, it's a question of how much risk you're willing to tolerate.  If you have a URL like `http://build:passw0rd@build.internal.example.com` where that internal hostname isn't externally accessible, you could argue that's "enough" security given the very guessable username and password and you don't need to go out of your way to hide it, especially if you think you can trust your end users.

Comment: Cool thanks! Our URL is public by the way, and though our remote artifact store access is restricted to our team, there are other teams that may use our docker registry in future. Definitely a vulnerability!

Answer (score 0):

You could use docker secret to pass variables to your settings.xml

enable secret by enablind buildkit in /etc/docker/daemon.json

```
    {
      "features": {
        "buildkit": true
      }
    }
```

create a settings.xml in your Dockerfile like this :

```
COPY <<-EOT /root/.m2/settings.xml
   <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
        <servers>
            <server>
                <id>ID</id>
                <username>\${username}</username>
                <password>\${password}</password>
            </server>
        </servers>
        
    </settings>
    EOT
```

Then you can use this RUN line to use secret

```
    RUN --mount=type=secret,id=my_env source /run/secrets/my_env \
      && mvn clean install -Dusername=${USERNAME} -Dpassword=${PASSWORD}
```

Build your DockerFile like this :

```
    docker build -t test --secret id=my_env,src=.env .
```

Store your secret in a file named .env like this in your Dockerfile folder :

```
USERNAME=toto
PASSWORD=toto
```

The secret is read in the RUN line then it is destroyed.